# Center TextField in MediumTopAppBar title

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-appbarlayout

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO**: I am trying to use a TextField inside the title of MediumTopAppBar.
**THE PROBLEM:** The TextField looks like it's been cut off from the top.

**MY CODE**

```
Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            MediumTopAppBar(
                title = {    

                    TextField(
                        value = "",
                        onValueChange = {/*TODO*/},
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(0.dp)
                            .height(40.dp)
                            .zIndex(1f)
                            .border(0.dp, Color.Transparent, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
                        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                            textColor = Color.Gray,
                            disabledTextColor = Color.Transparent,
                            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                            disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
                        ),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
                    )

                },
......
```

I tried to set the heigh of the TextField with smaller number

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Edx.png)

Comment: If you're using Material 3, consider using the [CenterAlignedTopAppBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#CenterAlignedTopAppBar(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarColors,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarScrollBehavior)). It's not clear to me why you're using a TextField instead of a Text (screenshot doesn't look like it's something the user should edit)? I'd also generally recommend not setting a height here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `BasicTextField` instead of a `TextField`:

```
MediumTopAppBar(
    title = {
        BasicTextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = { text = it },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(0.dp)
                .height(40.dp)
                .zIndex(1f)
                .border(0.dp, Color.Transparent, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            enabled = enabled,
            singleLine = singleLine
        ){
            TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
                value = text,
                innerTextField = it,
                enabled = enabled,
                singleLine = singleLine,
                visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                contentPadding = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldWithoutLabelPadding(
                    top = 0.dp,
                    bottom = 0.dp
                ),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    textColor = Color.Gray,
                    disabledTextColor = Color.Transparent,
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
                ),
            )
        }
    },
```